# Issue with state object converting rootReducer into combineReducers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have an app using redux that currently has the reducer file set as rootReducer but I need to expand it so I want to use combineReducers but I can't get it to work. Here is the code to my rootReducer which works fine in the app

```js
//Root Reducer

export default function rootReducer(state = {
    filtered: [],
  }, action) {

    switch (action.type) {
      case "SEARCH_IMAGES":
        let filtered = action.payload
       return {...state, images: action.payload, filtered, isFetching: false}
      
      default:
        return state
    }
  }
```

So I created a new reducer called filtered

```js
export default function (state = {
  filtered: []}, action) {
  
  switch (action.type) {
   
    case "SEARCH_IMAGES":
      let filtered = this.state.action.payload
      return {
         ...state, images: action.payload, filtered, isFetching: false
      };
      default:
      return state
    }
}
```

set up a comibined reducers index file to import the new reducer

```js
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import comments from './comments';
import filtered from './filtered';
import images from './images';

export default combineReducers({
  filtered, images
})
```

import it into my index and add it to my store and provider.
The issue seems to be with  `state = {
    filtered: []`
parameter. How do I get that to work in a new reducer using combined reducers.  How do I add the empty array for `filtered: []`

this is the error message I am receiving 
[image]

Here is the revised ImageContainer.js

```js
import React from 'react'
import ImageCard from './ImageCard'
import ContentLoader from 'react-content-loader'


class ImageContainer extends React.Component {
 
  render() {
    const { filtered } = this.props;
    const allImages = this.props.filtered.filtered.map((pic) => {
        return <ImageCard key={pic.id} pic={pic} url={pic.images[0]["link"]} />
    })
    return (
  
      <div className="image-wrapper">
        {allImages}
        <div className="note">
      {allImages.length === 0 ? "No memes are set for this query tag": ""}
      </div>
      </div>
     
    )
  }
}

export default ImageContainer
```

Portal Page

```js
import React from 'react'
import { Label } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import * as IchingTable from '../../constants/lookup.js';
import { HexagramImage } from '../HexagramImage.js';
import * as pictureActions from '../../actions/pictures'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import ImageContainer from './ImageContainer.js';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import classnames from 'classnames';
import { Segment } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import { NavLink, withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';


class PortalPage extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    this.state = {
      open: false,
      selectedTabId: 1,
      intervalId: null
    }
    
  }  
  componentDidMount() {
   
    let query = this.props.hexagram.tags[0].label 
    this.props.searchImages(query)
  }


 
 


  detailsback(hex) {
    
    this.props.history.push( `/details/${hex.number}/${hex.name}` );
    this.props;
    console.log("this is the bar hex");
    
  }
  
  
  labelClick = (label, event, selectedTabId, id) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    let query = event.target.innerText;    
    const { searchImages } = this.props
    searchImages(query);
    this.setState({ selectedTabId : label.id });
  }
  render() {
    let hexNumber = Number( this.props.match.params.number );
    let hex  = IchingTable.getHexagram( hexNumber );
    let {trigrams, name, number, description, tags, selectedTabId} = this.props.hexagram;
      let searchtags = (tags).map( (tag, label, id, index) => {
        let initActive = (match, location) => {
          if (!match) {
            return false
          }
          let selectedTabId = parseInt(match.selectedTabId)
          return this.state.selectedTabId === tag.id;
        }
    
        const params = new URLSearchParams(this.props)
        return (
          <div className="labeltags" key={label} >
          <Label 
              onClickCapture={this.labelClick.bind(null, tag)} 
              as={NavLink}
              to="/"
              activeClassName="slabel--active"
              basic size={'large'} 
              value={tag.id}
              key={label} 
              isActive={initActive}
              >
              {tag.label}
            </Label>
          </div>   
        );
      })
      
    return (
      <div>

          <Segment raised>
          <Label
            as='a'
            onClick={this.detailsback.bind(this, hex)}
            onTouchTap={this.detailsback.bind(this, hex)}
            ribbon='right'
            color='orange'
            >
             &#x2190; Back
            </Label> 
          <div className="hexagram-card">
            <HexagramImage below={trigrams.below} above={trigrams.above} />
            <div className="title">
              <h3>{number}: {name}</h3>
              <h2>{description}</h2>
            </div>
            
          </div>
          </Segment>
         
            <div>
            <p>Click on search terms for </p><h4>{name} - {description} </h4>
             {searchtags}
             
            </div>
          <div>
            <ImageContainer filtered={this.props.filtered} />
          </div>
         
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    filtered: state.filtered
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators(pictureActions, dispatch)
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(PortalPage))
```

Comment: are you getting your default state as you want?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please share the error you are getting?

Looking at your code, I see one bug (below is the corrected code):

```
export default function (state = {
  filtered: []}, action) {

  switch (action.type) {

    case "SEARCH_IMAGES":
      // calling this.state.action.payload is incorrect. "action" variable contains the payload
      let filtered = action.payload // Old Code - this.state.action.payload
      return {
         ...state, images: action.payload, filtered, isFetching: false
      };
      default:
      return state
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I just added the error message to the bottom of the code snippets.  Thanks

Comment: Did changing "let filtered = this.state.action.payload" to "let filtered = action.payload" work for you?

Comment: Yes I changed it to    "let filtered = action.payload" but still getting the error

Comment: Can you share ImageContainer.js Code? I want to see how are you connected to Redux store.

Comment: I just added the ImageContainer.js code.  "const allImages" is where I added the "filter.filter" fix.

Comment: How are you passing the props to the ImageContainer? Based on your ImageContainer code, it looks like you are not connected to redux store.

Comment: I added the parent component for that called PortalPage.js where I connect to redux via mapStateToProps

Answer (score 0):

> Your question is quite unclear. But what I could figure out is you
>   want to know how t work with combine reducers

This is how we work with combine reducers

reducer1.js

```
const somedefault = [];
    export default function (state = somedefault, action) {

      switch (action.type) {

        case "SEARCH_IMAGES":
          let filtered = action.payload
          return {
             ...state, images: action.payload, filtered, isFetching: false
          };
          default:
          return state
        }
    }
```

reducer2.js

```
const somedefault = {};
    export default function (state = somedefault, action) {

      switch (action.type) {
          default:
             return state
        }
    }
```

combineReducer.js

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import Red1 from './reducer1.js';
import Red2 from './reducer2.js';

export default combineReducers({
  red1: Red1,
  red2: Red2
})
```

So when you see your redux state then it will look like

```
state
|___red1: []
|___red2: {}
```